# Java Regex to strip all leading zeros in a delimited String

Tags: java, regex

I have the string "08,09,10,11" and I want "8,9,10,11" i.e. strip all leading zeros.

The regex

```
"08,09,10,11".replaceAll("^0+(?!$)", "")
```

is close but gives me '8,09,10,11' (i.e. the zero on the 9 is not stripped.

Anyone got a regex I can use to do what I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
str.replaceAll("(?<!\d)0+(?=\d+)", "");
```

And here are some tests: http://fiddle.re/rp57

Comment: @LukasKnuth It was literally a 5 second fix.

Answer (score 5):

This will work:

`str.replaceAll("^0+", "")`

Answer (score 2):

Here the different between two approaches mention:

```
str.replaceAll("^0+", "")

"0001000" ----> "1000"
"0000000" ----> ""


replaceAll("^0+(?!$)", "")

"0001000" ----> "1000"
"0000000" ----> "0"
```

(?!$) is a so called negative lookahead looking out for the end of the string and do not remove the "0" followed by the end of the string. therefore if a leading zero is also the last character of the string it does not get removed